# NomicLabsHardhatPluginError: The Etherscan API responded with a failure status

Tags: etherscan, hardhat, hardhat-deploy, api

**successfully deployed. but in vs-code giving this error. how to slove this ?? **

```
NomicLabsHardhatPluginError: The Etherscan API responded with a failure status.
The verification may still succeed but should be checked manually.
Reason: Already Verified
    at getVerificationStatus (D:\Codeing\Blockchain\hardhat\node_modules\@nomiclabs\hardhat-etherscan\src\etherscan\EtherscanService.ts:116:11)  
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at attemptVerification (D:\Codeing\Blockchain\hardhat\node_modules\@nomiclabs\hardhat-etherscan\src\index.ts:490:30)
    at SimpleTaskDefinition.action (D:\Codeing\Blockchain\hardhat\node_modules\@nomiclabs\hardhat-etherscan\src\index.ts:778:48)
    at Environment._runTaskDefinition (D:\Codeing\Blockchain\hardhat\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\runtime-environment.ts:311:14)       
    at Environment.run (D:\Codeing\Blockchain\hardhat\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\runtime-environment.ts:159:14)
    at SimpleTaskDefinition.verifySubtask [as action] (D:\Codeing\Blockchain\hardhat\node_modules\@nomiclabs\hardhat-etherscan\src\index.ts:312:28)
    at Environment._runTaskDefinition (D:\Codeing\Blockchain\hardhat\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\runtime-environment.ts:311:14)       
    at Environment.run (D:\Codeing\Blockchain\hardhat\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\runtime-environment.ts:159:14)
    at Environment._runTaskDefinition (D:\Codeing\Blockchain\hardhat\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\runtime-environment.ts:311:14)
```

Comment: Are you using the right Etherscan API in your config file?

Comment: It does this sometimes. It doesn't mean anything is wrong, it just takes some time. If it fails try again.

Comment: have you solved the problem ? I am facing the same issue.